# Why was a question about Textmate 2 closed as offtopic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I'm trying to understand a recent act of moderation and how to learn from it how to be a better user.

2 years ago I answered this question: [Ensure a new line at the EOF when saving a file in Textmate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42679033/1167956) [(cached)](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:pnTBsFVCq5AJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679033/ensure-a-new-line-at-the-eof-when-saving-a-file-in-textmate-2+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

In the past several days two users and a moderator voted to close the question as "off-topic". My answer got 2 chastising comments. All in what seems a very short timeline.

- Did something change here that would have highlighted this question to moderators?
- Do you see any reason to suspect foul play?
- Looking at the question; do you agree with it's deletion and the given reasoning?

I understand I could request reopening the question, but it's not clear to me that that's right either.

*About closing the question:*

This closure implies to me that "on topic" questions must be about code. Which in turn implies that all questions about editor configuration are off-topic. Is that so?

According to my research; ["on topic" is partially defined as](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
>   a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

[And this issue gets discussed regularly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169933/is-asking-for-programming-tool-recommendations-on-topic-on-stack-overflow)

Both links make me question the decision to close as off topic.

*About the comments on my answer:*

These comments agreed that the answer was poor because it is only a link. I was not as rigorous in answering as I would be today, and I generally agree with their point. Yet, this has been bothering me for the following reasons:

To provided more details than the link to the bundle seems "off  topic" in this case. I'd liken it to providing source code for a togglable setting in the app's GUI.

I could have suggested how to install the bundle, but that must be off topic.

I could have explained the code in the bundle, but that too must be off topic.

The bundle is very small. Any more explanation on the code in the bundle and I would have been recreating the bundle in my answer. To do so would have been answering a very different question and so, too, would have been off topic.

Were I able to answer in a way that satisfies the "not only a link" rule, would that warrant undeleting the question? What would that answer look like?

Comment: I'm sympathetic to this...it hasn't had a lot of traction since its inception but at the same time, I don't know how you could *not* have this just pointing to either the plugin or its source code.  Unless they wanted *pictures*.  And that just sounds silly.

Comment: Not a > 10k, so I can't see the question that is now deleted, so I can't help. Wish I could, but I can't.

Comment: @Chipster I've added the name of the question, as well as a link to the google cached version. The cached version lacks the comments in my question, I could reproduce them but I hesitate to directly quote others without the ability to cite them.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, since I'm not 10k, I can't investigate it further and answer most of your questions. That said, my best guess is aimed at the low-quality question, not your answer. However, your answer does mostly just give the link and doesn't expand it a lot. We try to discourage that kind of thing here. But you also said it's not up to your current standards anyway, so I don't really see a problem here.

Comment: You're basically stating you don't think it's possible for this question to be given a good answer and then wondering why it was deleted? Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: @RobertLongson No and no. I'm stating that I believe the question is on topic and I'm asking what I could have done better to answer the question.

Comment: I would undelete this question, but it was deleted by another moderator and I'm really not in the mood for a dispute.

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume for a moment that TextMate is a tool commonly used by developers, so we declare the question on-topic. I also happily ignore the comments left by the OP that your answer didn't solve their problem.

It is inevitable your answer has to link to an external resource as the feature asked for isn't present in the stock product.

How about this:

> TextMate doesn't have that feature. You have to rely on an external
>   bundle. I've found [Ensure New Line at the
>   EOF](https://github.com/mszyndel/Ensure-New-Line-at-the-EOF.tmbundle)
>   from [Mike Szyndel](https://github.com/mszyndel) to work. It does
>   require version 2.0.0-alpha.9317 or better.
>
> Following the readme, the easiest step is to clone that GitHub
>   repository to `~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles` (or
>   `~/Library/Application Support/Textmate/Bundles` if you are on a newer
>   version) and then relaunch TextMate.
>
> In the .tm_properties file you can exclude certain file extensions to
>   use that bundle:
>
> ```
> [*.csv] scopeAttributes =
> attr.do-not-ensure-new-line
> ```
>
> The
>   [readme.md](https://github.com/mszyndel/Ensure-New-Line-at-the-EOF.tmbundle/blob/master/README.md)
>   has a bit more details.

While this is barely more, it does tell visitors what version of textmate they need, how the install would work (if you are a user that has no idea what clone is, they might go looking for a different answer) and if this bundle screws up their whole textmate setup.

In the comments you say "download as ZIP". I have a faint idea what that will do but the installation steps are slightly different then. I would also address the issues brought forward by the OP and see if you can solve those, as simply copying the files in the right folder doesn't always seem to lead to success. That fact doesn't make your answer overly valuable, at least not for the OP.